# MYSQL PHP: Inserting into database many to many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have two questions :

I have 3 tables : EMTS , levels, and EMTS_has_levels. It is a many to many relationship between EMTS AND levels

My first question:

In `levels` table, I have 2 columns, idlevels(primary key)  and I have a column called `levelname` :

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`levels` (
  `idlevels` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `levelname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idlevels`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I want to insert multiple values to levelname. AN EMT might have multiple levels. SO what I did is add this to the  html form:

`<input type="checkbox" name="level" value="level1">Level1</input>`

`<input type="checkbox" name="level" value="level2">Level2</input>`

ANd in the register.php I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['level']))
{
    $name=$_POST['level'];
}
$stmt4=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO levels(levelsname) VALUES(?)");
$stmt4->bind_param("s",$name);
$stmt4->execute();
```

When I try the above php code I get an error. Idlevels isn't the reason as it should autoincrements, but why isn't the insertion to levelsname working?

My second question:
This is EMTS table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`EMTS` (
  `idEMTS` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `nuber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `shifts_idshifts` INT NULL,
  `bloodtype_id` INT NULL,
  `street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `building` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEMTS`),
  INDEX `fk_EMTS_shifts1_idx` (`shifts_idshifts` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_EMTS_bloodtype1_idx` (`bloodtype_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `nickname_UNIQUE` (`nickname` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EMTS_shifts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`shifts_idshifts`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`shifts` (`idshifts`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EMTS_bloodtype1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`bloodtype_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`bloodtype` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is my EMTS_has_levels table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`EMTS_has_levels` (
  `levels_idlevels` INT NULL,
  `EMTS_idEMTS` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`levels_idlevels`, `EMTS_idEMTS`),
  INDEX `fk_levels_has_EMTS_EMTS1_idx` (`EMTS_idEMTS` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_levels_has_EMTS_levels1_idx` (`levels_idlevels` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_levels_has_EMTS_levels1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`levels_idlevels`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`levels` (`idlevels`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_levels_has_EMTS_EMTS1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EMTS_idEMTS`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`EMTS` (`idEMTS`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

`EMTS_has_levels` has only two columns that are foriegn keys . First one is `levels_idlevels` referencing levels table, and the second one is `EMTS_idEMTS` referencing `idEMTS` from `EMTS` table.

My question is say I filled `EMTS` and I filled `levels` how can I fill the two foreign keys in `EMTS_has_levels`?

I tried this but it gives me an error:

```
 $stmt10=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO belongs(levels_idlevels) SELECT idlevels FROM levels WHERE levelname=$_POST['levelname'] " );
    $stmt10->execute();
$stmt11=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO belongs(EMTS_idEMTS) SELECT idEMTS FROM EMTS WHERE nickname=$_POST['nickname'] " );
$stmt11->execute();
```

How can I fill the third table that results from the many to many relationship?

Comment: You have a typo: The name of the column is `levelname`, but you're inserting into `levelsname`. But why is this form inserting into the `levels` table? If you're linking an EMT to a level, you should only be inserting into `belongs`.

Comment: This looks wrong too `$stmt4->bind_param("s",$name);` as you have a question mark as a placeholder.

Comment: `password VARCHAR(45)` - Right away, this suggests an unsafe password hashing method. One such as `password_hash()`, stores a 60 length char. If you plan on using this or are using it already, it already failed you, *silently*.

Comment: you also need to treat your checkbox inputs as arrays, given the same name attributes. If you only require one to be checked, don't use those but radios instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow multiple levels, you need to use an array-style name so you get all of them.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="level1">Level1</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="level2">Level2</input>
```

Then you can loop over all the values. And you need to insert just once into `EMTS_has_levels`, getting `level_idlevel` from the `levels` table, and `EMTS_idEMTS` from the `EMTS` table

```
$stmt4=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO EMTS_has_levels (levels_idlevels, EMTS_idEMTS)
    SELECT l.idlevel, e.idEMTS
    FROM levels AS l
    CROSS JOIN EMTS AS e
    WHERE l.levelname = ?
    AND e.nickname = ?");
$stmt4->bind_param("s",$name, $_POST['nickname']);
foreach ($_POST['level'] as $name) {
    $stmt4->execute();
}
```